# In PowerShell why does "casting" to FileInfo set the wrong FullName, Directory, and DirectoryName

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm noticing a VERY odd behavior in both my PS ISE and PS when I'm getting a `FileInfo` object by calling

```
$FileInfo = [System.IO.FileInfo](".\SomeFile.ext")
```

When I look at its properties the `DirectoryName` and its related properties all default to the ORIGINAL path that PS opens in.

Here's a copy from my ISE which launches as an administrator with `c:\Windows\System32` as the default path

If I run the following code:

```
$Fileinfo = [System.IO.FileInfo](".\@OpenWithToastLogo.png")  
cd c:\temp  
$Fileinfo2 = [System.IO.FileInfo](".\activation.txt")  
z:  
$Fileinfo3 = [System.IO.FileInfo](".\7za.exe")  
$Fileinfo | fl *
$Fileinfo2 | fl *
$Fileinfo3 | fl *
```

I get

> VersionInfo       :
>   File              : C:\WINDOWS\system32\@OpenWithToastLogo.png
>   InternalName      :
>   OriginalFilename  :
>   FileVersion       :
>   FileDescription   :
>   Product           :
>   ProductVersion    :
>   Debug             : False
>   Patched           : False
>   PreRelease        : False
>   PrivateBuild      : False
>   SpecialBuild      : False
>   Language          :
>   BaseName          : @OpenWithToastLogo
>   Target            : {C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-openwith_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_7f75eaad41c1f239\@OpenWithToastLogo.png,C:\Windows\SysWOW64\@OpenWithToastLogo.png}
>   LinkType           : HardLink
>   Mode               : -a---l
>   Name               : @OpenWithToastLogo.png
>   Length             : 160
>   DirectoryName      : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   Directory          : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   IsReadOnly         : False
>   Exists             : True
>   FullName           : C:\WINDOWS\system32\@OpenWithToastLogo.png
>   Extension          : .png 
>   CreationTime       : 7/10/2015 7:00:32 AM
>   CreationTimeUtc    : 7/10/2015 11:00:32 AM
>   LastAccessTime     : 7/10/2015 7:00:32 AM
>   LastAccessTimeUtc  : 7/10/2015 11:00:32 AM
>   LastWriteTime      : 7/10/2015 7:00:32 AM
>   LastWriteTimeUtc   : 7/10/2015 11:00:32 AM
>   Attributes         : Archive
>
> VersionInfo       :
>   BaseName          : activation 
>   Target            :
>   LinkType          :
>   Mode              : darhsl
>   Name              : activation.txt
>   Length            :
>   DirectoryName     : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   Directory         : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   IsReadOnly        : True
>   Exists            : False
>   FullName          : C:\WINDOWS\system32\activation.txt
>   Extension         : .txt
>   CreationTime      : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   CreationTimeUtc   : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
>   LastAccessTime    : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
>   LastWriteTime     : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   LastWriteTimeUtc  : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
>   Attributes        : -1
>
> VersionInfo       :
>   BaseName          :
>   7za Target        :
>   LinkType          :
>   Mode              : darhsl
>   Name              : 7za.exe
>   Length            :
>   DirectoryName     : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   Directory         : C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   IsReadOnly        : True
>   Exists            : False
>   FullName          : C:\WINDOWS\system32\7za.exe
>   Extension         : .exe
>   CreationTime      : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   CreationTimeUtc   : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM 
>   LastAccessTime    : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
>   LastWriteTime     : 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
>   LastWriteTimeUtc  : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
>   Attributes        : -1

With my regular account it defaults to my `H:\` path so the same test would have `H:\` as the `DirectoryName`.

And yes, each of these files ONLY exists in the directory it was relative to.

Has anyone seen this before, and do they know a good fix? Using fully qualified of course works but this is for a script that other technicians might run and we're all pretty used to the idea of using relative pathing with PS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PowerShell has a notion of your current location.  You can see this
>   using the `$pwd` automatic variable or the `Get-Location` cmdlet [..]
>
> This path is used by PowerShell to resolve relative paths at the level of
>   the PowerShell API.
>
> [..]
>
> Applications have a notion of the current directory.  This is the
>   directory used to resolve relative paths at the level of the Windows
>   API.
>
> **How you Get Burned**
>
> Your current location may or may not be the same as your current directory.

- From http://www.beefycode.com/post/The-Difference-between-your-Current-Directory-and-your-Current-Location.aspx

and

> One question that comes up frequently is, “Why does PowerShell not
>   change its `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory` as I navigate around
>   the shell?”
>
> One of the difficult aspects of this comes from the fact that
>   PowerShell supports multiple pipelines of execution.  Although it’s
>   not directly exposed yet, users will soon be able to suspend jobs to
>   the background, and other concurrent tasks.
>
> The current directory affects the entire process, so if we change the
>   directory as you navigate around the shell, you risk corrupting the
>   environment of jobs you have running in the background.
>
> When you use filenames in .Net methods, the best practice is to use
>   fully-qualified path names. The `Resolve-Path` cmdlet makes this easy:
>
> `$reader = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader (Resolve-Path baseline.xml)`

- From http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/07/18/set-location-and-environmentcurrentdirectory/

Comment: That makes complete sense.

Thanks for the reading materials.

So does that mean ANY time I'm using that [.NET Class]"Something" that something had better be a fully qualified path or i'll run into the same issue.

Looks like i might have to figure another way to write my cmdlet since i was trying to pass in the string path to be loaded as a fileinfo parameter.

Oh well off to find another way to skin this cat.

Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't know about this and it was someone else who pointed me to the `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory` connection, so it's new to me - but it looks that way, use fully qualified paths, yes.