# How to write a Powershell file parameter that accepts a relative path

Tags: powershell, parameters

The following sample code correctly reads both the PSD1 and the regular file when the path to the PSD1 is a fully qualified path (or when the current location is the same as the current directory).
It fails when supplied a relative path.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.IO.FileInfo]$PsdFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.IO.FileInfo]$RegularFile = 'testfile'
)

$RegularFileContent = Get-Content $RegularFile
$PsdData = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory $PsdFile.DirectoryName -FileName $PsdFile.Name

echo "regular file contents: $RegularFileContent"

echo "Psd data:"
echo $PsdData.Name
```

How can I fix this so the user can enter a relative path?

I believe the underlying problem is similar to the problem described in [this post about FileInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309256/in-powershell-why-does-casting-to-fileinfo-set-the-wrong-fullname-directory) but I don't know how to incorporate `Resolve-Path` or similar into the parameter handling.

Comment: Relative to *what*?  The script root?  The user's session?

Comment: This fails if the `$PsdFile` is not a fully qualified path. So any relative path causes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of your question hinges on *which* relative you're referring to as that itself is *relative*.  If you want the path to be relative to a user's working directory versus the script's root, you can accomplish that like so:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $PsdFile,

    [Parameter()] # Mandatory is $false by default
    [string]
    $RegularFile = 'testfile'
)

[System.IO.FileInfo]$psd = Join-Path -Path $PWD.Path -ChildPath $PsdFile

$data = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory $psd.DirectoryName -FileName $PsdFile.Name
$content = Get-Content -Path $RegularFile

"regular file contents: $content"
"Psd data:" + $data.Name
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to let this sink in a bit, I had been looking at this for too long yesterday to understand your comment about why that made a difference. I still feel that the problem occurs no matter which is being entered but obviously the solution will differ. This solution works. I just want to test what happens when you specify something that is not a valid (relative) path.

Answer (score 1):

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript( {
            if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $_ ) ) { throw "File not found." }
            elseif (-Not (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf) ) { throw "PsdFile should be a file." }
            return $true
        })]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $PsdFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateScript( {
            if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $_ ) ) { throw "File not found." }
            elseif (-Not (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf) ) { throw "PsdFile should be a file." }
            return $true
        })]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $RegularFile = 'testfile'
)

$PsdFile = (Resolve-Path -Path $PsdFile).Path;
$RegularFile = (Resolve-Path -Path $RegularFile).Path;

$RegularFileContent = Get-Content $RegularFile.FullName
$PsdData = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory $PsdFile.DirectoryName -FileName $PsdFile.Name
```

Comment: This approach is usually better because `Resolve-Path` will output errors for invalid paths and it will resolve paths relative to `($PWD).Path` -- which is the same as `(Get-Location).Path`